# SwiftUI Stepper save value

Tags: swiftui, save, userdefaults, stepper

How can I save the value of the stepper in the UserDefaults every time I press `+` or `-`?

I don't want a separate save button.

```
struct Settings: View {
    @State private var zielwert = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "zielwert")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper("Zielwert \(zielwert)", value: $zielwert, in: 90...160)
            Button("Speichern") {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.zielwert, forKey: "zielwert")
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 23.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SwiftUI 2**

Use `AppStorage`:

```
struct Settings: View {
    @AppStorage("zielwert") private var zielwert = 90

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper("Zielwert \(zielwert)", value: $zielwert, in: 90...160)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 23.0)
    }
}
```

**SwiftUI 1**

Use `.onReceive`:

```
import Combine

struct Settings: View {
    @State private var zielwert = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "zielwert")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper("Zielwert \(zielwert)", value: $zielwert, in: 90...160)
                .onReceive(Just(zielwert)) { zielwert in
                    print(zielwert)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(zielwert, forKey: "zielwert")
                }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 23.0)
    }
}
```